# Do we need to create separate tables for diff types of recharges such as(mobilerech,dthrech,elecbill, waterbill, etc) or can done in 1 table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

I am working on a project for recharge and bill payments. I am confused about whether to use a single table for all type of recharges like mobile recharge, dtn recharge, electricity bill, water bill, card recharges, etc, which is difficult or do I create separate tables for each type of recharge and work on them.

**Table has colums** 
recharge_id PRIMARY KEY, 
recharge_amount , 
recharge_status, 
recharge_time, 
user_id, 
payment_id

The data has to be added into the table when there is any recharge process with status and other details.

Comment: Provide more explanations about your app needs, and how does your tables look like, or what data they'll contain.

Comment: Thanks for giving your suggestion, sir. I have added more explanation to the question.

Comment: We can do whatever we like, but generally we store the same kind of thing in the same table

Comment: You could have a recharge_type column that would discriminate between mobile, dtn, elec, ... on the upside all your data is in a nice table and you can add a new recharge without modifying your datamodel. On the downside if you have recharge type specific information you'll need to store it in an extra table. My experience is the pros outweigh the cons.

Comment: @AbhishekSirohi It is better to put them in separate tables... in that way, it is easier to fetch data later on, and joins are meant for this purpose... and easier to add extra columns when needed in future.

Answer (score 0):

Although, you didn't show anything you tried, i think this is a viable question.
A possible approach would be to create one table for your type and one for your recharges

Something like the following should work

create a table recharge_type like

```
+----+------------------+--------+
| id |       name       | active |
+----+------------------+--------+
|  1 | Mobile recharge  |      1 |
|  2 | Dtn recharge     |      1 |
|  3 | electricity bill |      1 |
|  4 | water bill       |      1 |
|  5 | card recharge    |      1 |
+----+------------------+--------+
```

and your table recharge

```
+----+------------------+---------+------------+--------+--------+------------+
| id | recharge_type_id | user_id | payment_id | amount | status |    time    |
+----+------------------+---------+------------+--------+--------+------------+
|  1 |                1 |       1 |          1 |   2.00 |      1 | 2019-03-05 |
|  2 |                2 |       1 |          2 |   3.00 |      3 | 2019-03-05 |
|  3 |                2 |       1 |          2 |   4.00 |      4 | 2019-03-05 |
+----+------------------+---------+------------+--------+--------+------------+
```

With this type of construction you are pretty flexible for nearly any approach.

> If you want to understand why this is a good approach, you should read
>   some articles about first normal form. You can find an article
>   [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. Very helpful.